# Document design - Update comments

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm playing around some with RavenDb and documents.

Let's say that I got the following document:

```
BlogEntry
    Id
    Title
    UserId
    Comments
        Title
        Body
```

How would I handle comment edits? They are not very frequent, but should be possible.

Is it something like:

1. Load document
2. Find the correct comment
3. Update it
4. Save document

Should I put some kind of id in the comment child doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is probably best, you can see how we handle that with RaccoonBlog